# Unable to get PropertyChanged.Fody to work in Xamarin.Forms App

Tags: xamarin.forms, fody-propertychanged

I'm trying to implement PropertyChanged.Fody in my Xamarin.Forms app. I followed this blog post:

https://xamgirl.com/validation-snippets-in-xamarin-forms/

and used the following git project as a reference:

https://github.com/CrossGeeks/ValidationXFSample.

I'm able to get the validations to work once I press the submit button. However, the validations do not trigger when the field is updated. I'm also unable to get t the example project to work. It properly displays the validations on submit, but not when the field is updated.

I'm using the latest Visual Studio on Mac and iOS Simulator 14.3. Otherwise, I use the defaults of the example project.

Comment: Any reason why not using the [pre-built validation behaviors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/behaviors/validationbehavior) from xamarin community toolkit package ? With Flags="ValidateOnValueChanging"

Comment: please post the relevant code.  Linking to a blog post or repo is not sufficient,

Comment: I posted the github repo, since I'm unable to get that project to work either. I will look into the Xamarin Toolkit. I didn't see that. It might be a much better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make your life easier in the future use the [pre-built validation behaviors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/behaviors/validationbehavior) from xamarin community toolkit package (contains lot of repetitive/common stuff used by dev). Email validation, max characters validation, custom validation.. and more out of the box. Regarding when to validate you can set `Flags="ValidateOnValueChanging"`.

Answer (score 0):

I have another work around that similar like this.
Here is my nuget config

[image]

and this is my BaseViewModel

[image]

Explanation:

1. Simply add ReactiveAttribute to property you want to

   `[Reactive] public bool IsLoading { get; set; }`
2. If you want to handle when the value changed, just add new method with this format `On<Property_Name>Changed` change <Property_Name> with the property name you want to be handled like `OnIsLoadingChanged()`
3. Make sure your `BaseViewModel` implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`
4. This approach depend on `ReactiveUI` but it will not use all feature of `ReactiveUI`. You can freely to use another MVVM framework or just use pure `Xamarin.Forms`
5. This approach use the power of `PropertyChanged.Fody` and the simplicity of `ReactiveUI.Fody` sintax to declare property changed
6. You just need to add these library to your shared project and nothing todo in platforms specific

I can bind `IsLoading` just like

```
<ListView
    IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"
    IsRefreshing="{Binding IsLoading}">
</ListView>
```